# Formatting JSON date to Swift date doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format this date: `2018-01-10T11:57:21.153` to Swift `Date` object like this:

```
let dateSentString = jsonDict["date"] as! String
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateSentString)!
```

For some reason, the app crashes on the last line.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The string does not match the date format ...

Comment: @MartinR Why not? What is wrong with the date format?

Comment: Did you compare them exactly? What about the ".153" part? – All details in https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: `let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateSentString)!` is causing the crash? Because you used `!`, so it means that `dateFormatter.date(from: dateSentString)` is nil. Why is it nil, because your `dateformat` is wrong then. You don't manage the `.153` in yours for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the milli seconds format use 'SSS' specifier (with number of S's equal to number of digits of milliseconds ). for more information you get [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

from

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

**Full code**

```
   let dateSentString = "2018-01-10T11:57:21.153"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateSentString)!
    print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set formatter for date you are getting from JSON and then another formatter for the date you want.
First convert string fro JSON to a date variable by setting same format coming in JSON object .
Then you have to re-format that date variable into format you want.

I can write code if you want but it is better to try yourself.

Happy Coding